# Hide the directory in the address bar of the browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The file .htaccess has this directive:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^$ /moby/
```

When I type the website address into the address bar in the browser: `http://mobyx.net/` it appears the directory redirected to: `http://mobyx.net/moby/`

How to hide the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently doing a redirect (you tell the client to try again on `mobyx.net/moby` if they go to `mobyx.net`). What you actually want to do is an internal rewrite. This is invisible to the client. You can use `RewriteRule` for that. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for more information.

First make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in httpd.conf. Then add the following to your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^$ /moby/ [L]
```

This will internally rewrite `http://mobyx.net/` to `http://mobyx.net/moby/`, but not `http://mobyx.net/index.php` for example. If you want everything to be rewritten on your site, use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moby
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /moby/$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite the url if it doesn't already point to the /moby subdirectory.

Comment: Not found httpd.conf in my server.

Comment: Google what it is and where you can find it. If you don't have access to it, just try if it works...

Comment: Not found httpd.conf in my server.
I do this:

# Redirect to your directory
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /moby/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moby
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /moby/$1 [L]

But still shows the moby in the address bar.

Comment: Thank you; was necessary to clear the caches of the browsers, and there worked....